# How to add a comment in a SVG file using Inkscape?

Tags: svg, comments

I am using Inkscape to create SVG files.

Is it possible to put a comment in a SVG file? For example I want to leave a comment to mention the licence of the file (which is Creative Commons). And then, anyone who will download the file will be able to check it's licence by simply opening it with a text editor/viewer, so they won't have to worry if it's free or not.

I know that I can edit the SVG file using a text editor and I can add HTML comments (using < !-- .. -- >) or maybe I can add a "licence" under the height="480", But I prefer to use Inkscape, to make sure the comment will stay there and it will not be deleted when I save it again from within Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably the SVG metadata section.
You can fill it with InkScape by going to  File >> Document Properties
and then select the tab Metadata. There are several field that you can fill.

I've been using some fields and so far they haven't been deleted after modifying and saving the file.

In case you are saving your file in Optimized SVG format make sure you have unchecked the option "Remove metadata".

Thomas